# how to change the default font and font size of NSMutableAttributedString

Tags: ios, swift, nsmutableattributedstring

I'm using swift. Is there any way to change default font/ font size etc of an NSMutableAttributedString? Clearly I could set those values specifically for a given range - but that will then override any specific settings in the string.

Comment: "Clearly I could set those values specifically for a given range - but that will then override any specific settings in the string" Not if you set them _first_ for the _whole_ attributed string.

Answer (score 0):

You can use like that

```
let yourAttributes = [NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.preferredFontForTextStyle(UIFontTextStyleHeadline), NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.blackColor()]

let yourString = NSAttributedString(string: "Here my string !", attributes: yourAttributes)
```

Thanks

Comment: Thanks for reply! Actually i've to append text to the string with other font format like doing bold or italic on particular word. So first need to set default font/ font size of string.  Please guide me on it.. Thanks